# How to programmatically Run Script in EA

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

Is it possible to trigger a Script programmatically in EA similar to Package Baseline?

Is there having any way to do like below API "**CreateBaseline**" for to run the script?

"**CreateBaseline(PackageGUID,version,Notes)**"

Comment: I don't get what you want. How is CreateBaseline connected with triggering scripts at all?

Comment: which kind of script, how would you call it( would you call it from another script, or from an external program?)